# C# .Net 6 Webjob project not generating Package and PubTemp folders on build/rebuild inside obj folder

Tags: msbuild, .net-6.0, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have 2 webjobs in .net 6. One of the webjobs always creates the Package and the PubTmp folders inside obj\Release\net6.0 folder on build and rebuild. The other webjob doesn't. We need these folder for a task in Azure devops pipeline.
Where could it be defined or configured to generate the two folders in the first webjob.
Don't see any code or command for these folders to be created either in publishing profile or csproj files. Also did a text search in the entire project folder for anything that defines these folders. What am I missing and how do I configure the second webjob to produce these two folders on build?

Comment: Build the app and check once.

Comment: If possible can you please share the code repo.

Comment: Not possible to share the code repo. I have tried building and rebuilding multiple times

Comment: Do you have any build errors ?

Comment: When you rebuilt the project on your local environment, was the issue reproducible?

Comment: @Harshitha: No build errors

Comment: @AlvinZhao Yes...reproducible

Comment: @user9057272 - It is hard to reproduce from my end without the code, As Iam unable to reproduce the issue with my code.

Comment: @user9057272 What is the Visual Studio Version you are using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Can you please shaer the screencap of the folder for both the webjobs .